# In PySpark groupBy, how do I calculate execution time by group?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using PySpark for a university project, where I have large dataframes and I apply a PandasUDF, using `groupBy`. Basically the call looks like this:

```
df.groupBy(col).apply(pandasUDF)
```

I am using 10 cores in my Spark config (`SparkConf().setMaster('local[10]')`).

The goal is to be able to report the time each group took to run my code. I want the time each group takes to finish so that I can take the average. I am also interested in calculating the standard deviation.

I now am testing with cleaned data that I know will be separated into 10 groups, and I have the UDF print the running time using `time.time()`. But, if I am to use more groups this is not going to be possible to do (for context, all my data will be separated into 3000-something groups). Is there a way to measure the execution time per group?

Comment: To calculate and report the execution time for each call to the UDF I think you need to do that in the UDF as you are currently doing. If you wanted the total execution time, you could add the calculated execution time to a Spark Accumulator and then print it at the end of your application. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I'm not interested in the total time. This I could easily do on my notebook as well. I want the time each group takes to finish so that I can take the average. Perhaps I can try to save in a variable, but I'm not sure this can happen and my udf has to return something else.

Comment: You don’t have to return the time spent. Just print it and then check container logs (if Yarn).

Comment: If don't want to print the execution time to stdout then does returning it as an extra column from the Pandas UDF do what you need?

Comment: Yes, adding the same number to all the rows on the group is what I was thinking and what I will probably do, unless I find a way to populate a local list as the udf runs and then save to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't want to print the execution time to stdout you could return it as an extra column from the Pandas UDF instead e.g.

```
@pandas_udf("my_col long, execution_time long", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_pandas_udf(pdf):
    start = datetime.now()
    # Some business logic
    return pdf.assign(execution_time=datetime.now() - start)
```

Alternatively, to compute the average execution time in the driver application, you could accumulate the execution time and the number of UDF calls in the UDF with two [Accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators). e.g.

```
udf_count = sc.accumulator(0)
total_udf_execution_time = sc.accumulator(0)

@pandas_udf("my_col long", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_pandas_udf(pdf):
    start = datetime.now()
    # Some business logic
    udf_count.add(1)
    total_udf_execution_time.add(datetime.now() - start)
    return pdf

# Some Spark action to run business logic

mean_udf_execution_time = total_udf_execution_time.value / udf_count.value
```

Comment: thanks for the accumulator suggestion, it looks very useful. If I also wanted to have the standard deviation of the running times I guess I would have to go with the 1st approach (adding a new col) right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.